# Igraph: Extract nodes layout from a network and use it for another

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, network-analysis

I would like to compare two plots of graphs(an observed graph and a simulated one) that have the exact same nodes.
I would like to keep the nodes position fix so I can compare the difference in the edge's distribution.
I have tried set.seed but it's just keeping the plot identical every time I run it.
Is there a way to take the layout of a graph and use it for the other?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw, I guess you can use the `layout` argument of `plot`:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g1 <- ba.game(20, dir=F)
g2 <- ba.game(20, dir=F)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
coords <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g1)
plot(g1, layout = coords)
plot(g2, layout = coords)
```

[image]